# KableExtra conditional tables in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, xaringan

I am working on replicating in a Rmarkdown a report I made in Excel.

In some of the results I have tables with conditional columns with color formatting, from red to green (red for the lowest data and green for the highest data).

Here an example:

[image: example]

I have searched but the closest I found was to do this:

```
df %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(2, color = "white",
              background = spec_color(df$B,begin=0, end = 1,option='D'))
```

[image: Result]

My problem now is that the spec_color() argument only has 5 color maps and none of them go from red to green.

Does anyone know how I could add a colormap for the conditional formatting just like the one I used in Excel?

I am new using Rmarkdowns, thanks.

Comment: Maybe  this question  helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639647/background-color-in-kableextra-table-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of coloring the columns is by using `data_color` from `{gt}` package.
You can specify the colors in various ways, including manually supplying the names of your desired colors available in `grDevices::colors()`. You can also specify the domain with the range of the values in the targeted column.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

iris[45:55,c(1,5)] %>% gt() %>%
    data_color(columns = Sepal.Length, colors = scales::col_numeric(
        palette = c("tomato","yellow", "green4"), 
        domain = range(Sepal.Length)))
```

which results in the following colors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually work through the cells setting the colour.

There is a reason they don't use red-green as a scale. 1:12 men can't tell what colour it is.  Just because excel let's you do it, doesn't mean you should!

Flextable may offer an easier way

Comment: For the record, according to at least [one source](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/colour-vision-deficiency/), it's 1 in 12 men (as you said) and 1 in 200 women. I say this only because I thought it odd to only mention "men", and I wasn't certain if it was informed by publications (yes) or really just a generic reference to "people" (it was not). Thanks for the stat, CALUM Polwart.