# Adding a color legend for a kableextra table with background color

Tags: r, kableextra

I used a function I found on this stackoverflow answer ([Background color in kableextra table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639647/background-color-in-kableextra-table-column)) to create a heat map table in Kable extra. A reproducible example:

```
# Test for putting legend on table
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggsci)
library(paletteer)

# A function to use different palettes for heat map
spec_color2 <- function(x, alpha = 1, begin = 0, end = 1,
         direction = 1, option = "D",
         na_color = "#BBBBBB", scale_from = NULL,
         palette = viridisLite::viridis(256, alpha, begin, end, direction, option)) {
  n <- length(palette)
  if (is.null(scale_from)) {
    x <- round(scales::rescale(x, c(1, n)))
  } else {
    x <- round(scales::rescale(x, to = c(1, n),
                       from = scale_from))
  }
  
  color_code <- palette[x]
  color_code[is.na(color_code)] <- na_color
  return(color_code)
}

# Test data
(test <- tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  0.001,   0.230,
  0.5690,   0.500,
  0.015,   0.336
)
)

# Format table
(test_formatted <- test %>% mutate_if(is.double, round, digits=3) %>% mutate_if(is.double, format, digits = 3, nsmall = 3, scientific = FALSE))

# Create heat map table 
kbl(test_formatted, booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, caption = "Caption", escape = FALSE, linesep = "", col.names = c('Column A', 'Column B')) %>%
  column_spec(1, color = "black", background = spec_color2(test$colA, palette = paletteer_d("ggsci::blue_material"), scale_from = c(0, 0.6))) %>% 
  column_spec(2, color = "black", background = spec_color2(test$colB, palette = paletteer_d("ggsci::blue_material"), scale_from = c(0, 0.6)))
```

This works great, and I am able to make a table in RMarkdown, knitting to a PDF.

I would like to be able to add a legend showing my range of colors. I can't find a way to do this with KableExtra

Comment: May this be a starting point? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041042/how-to-plot-just-the-legends-in-ggplot2